# Will they ever make LEGO The Amazing Spider-man 2 sets?

Tags: minifigures, collectable-minifigures

I realized that they released an exclusive minifigure of The Amazing Spider-Man 2 in the San Diego Comic Con but I am still wondering if they will ever make LEGO set(s) based on the movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on licensing as well. Note that they have made sets for Ultimate Spiderman. The X-Men designs all follow their comic counterparts. Loki, Thor etc follow their Movie style counterparts.

This suggests that they have the license for the comic and animated styles, but Fox and Sony retain the rights for the movie looks of the characters.

Comment: This is correct. Lego does not have a licensing agreement with Sony who owns the movie rights to Spider-Man. They currently Spider-Man sets based only on Marvel IP. (Note that the "Amazing Spider-Man 2" designation for the Comic-Con exclusive from 2013 does not actually name that film anywhere on the package.)

Answer (score 0):

That depends. First of all, the movie needs to leave theaters. Seeing how LEGO has not made an Amazing Spider Man 1 set, it is fairly un-likely they will do sets for the sequel.

Comment: The movie doesn't need to leave theatres before Lego makes sets for it. Lego had a license for the first two Spider-Man movies in the early 2000s and their sets were released before the movie, as are most movie tie-in sets.

Answer (score -1):

Actually yes the will Because in 2014 October Sony has SIGNED lego tasm to Lego They made a electro Polybag that was given out But thats all i know but yeah They will make some because they have Rights to

Comment: This is just speculation.  Do you have any sources to back this up?  Also, please try cleaning up your grammar and spelling.